# Extract a value from a string

Tags: android, regex, string

I am trying to extract a value from a string.

The string: **"at Amazon *APPSTORE.FX rates and charges are applicable.";**

from the above text I would like extract only: **Amazon *APPSTORE**

So I tried the following:

Log.e("transaction","value "+gettext(str));

```
public static String gettext(String stringtext)
{
        return stringtext.substring(stringtext.lastIndexOf("at")+2, stringtext.lastIndexOf(".")).trim() ;
}
```

But I am getting results like this:

```
es and charges are applicable
```

It is taking at from rates and printing the other string but not the string from first **"at"**?

Why?

Comment: Why not use `indexOf` instead of `lastIndexOf`

Comment: how to use it on this?

Comment: `stringtext.substring(stringtext.indexOf("at")+2, stringtext.indexOf("."))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `indexOf()` instead of `lastIndexOf()` for more details check http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=225

`stringtext.substring(stringtext.indexOf("at")+2, stringtext.indexOf(".")).trim())`

Comment: My bad. Thanks a lot. This gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

lastIndexOf() looks for the **last** occurrence of a substring in an string. So it finds "at" in "rates". Same goes for the "."

See http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=225

For your example you could simply use indexOf() instead. Or even something more specific like:

```
return stringtext.substring(stringtext.indexOf("at Amazon")+2, stringtext.indexOf(".FX")).trim() ;
```

Comment: My bad. I got the logic for indexof... Thanks a lot. This gives the result.